# strcmp[c++] error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, pointers, char, strcmp

Where am doing wrong in this code? I need only in `char` types, please don't suggest to use `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    char *mystring="C:/windows";
    char last_char;
    last_char = mystring[strlen(mystring)-1];
    cout<<"Input: " <<mystring<<endl;
    if(strcmp(last_char,";")!=0)
    {
        strcat(mystring,";");
    }
    cout<<"Output: "<<mystring<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    Compilation error    time: 0 memory: 3340 signal:0
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:7:17: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
  char *mystring="C:/windows";
                 ^
prog.cpp:11:25: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
  if(strcmp(last_char,";")!=0)
                         ^
In file included from prog.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:140:12: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int strcmp(const char*, const char*)’ [-fpermissive]
 extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
```

Comment: The type of last_char is char, `strcmp` requires char* as parameter. Use `if(last_char == ';')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `strcmp`, it expects a null terminated characters sequence. Instead, use direct comparison:

```
if (last_char == ';') ...
```

Also, your code invokes undefined behavior in the `strcat()` call. `my_string` was initialized with a string literal, thus, you are not allowed to modify it, since the implementation is free to place it in read-only memory (and typically will do so).

You can declare it like this instead:

```
char mystring[12] = "C:/windows"; // space for one more char
```

Comment: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Comment: Are you sure you inserted single quotes around `;` instead of double quotes?

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I did it now it throwed another error - Runtime error  time: 0 memory: 3340 signal:11
Input: C:/windows
Code pasted here: http://ideone.com/yb6ZiF

Comment: @user2754070 Please read my updated answer. You can't use `strcat` with `mystring`, because it will attempt to modify `mystring`, which is not allowed.

Comment: @user2754070 Which part of _"`my_string` was initialized with a string literal, thus, you are not allowed to modify it"_ you don't get ?

Comment: Got it Filipe, what is the max range that a char array hold? Because I need to hold the `Path Env variable of System (Windows)`.

Comment: Well, since it's a local array, it depends on the size of the process' stack. I would say you can safely hold the path environment variable, it's not big enough for you to worry about it, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

`last_char` is not a string. It is a character. You can't compare a `char` with string.
Try this instead

```
 if (last_char == ';') {...}
```

Statement

```
 strcat(mystring,";");
```

invokes undefined behavior. You can't modify a string literal as it resides in read only section of the memory.

Comment: Hum. The error you mentioned is not exactly because he's trying to modify the string literal, it's because the call to `strcmp()`, as is, is attempting to convert a char (`last_char`), to `const char *` to pass it on to `strcmp()`. These are not compatible types, hence the error.